# Is there an elegant way of determining if two dates are separated by a week of year in Swift?

Tags: swift

If I have two dates, and I want to know if one of them falls on a week of year (as defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1416908-weekofyear)) just prior to the other, how can I figure this out in Swift?

Assuming I don't care about time, one approach could be:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let startOfDate1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date1)
let startOfDate2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: date2)
let date1WeekOfYear = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: startOfDate1).weekOfYear!
let date2WeekOfYear = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: startOfDate2).weekOfYear!
if (date1WeekOfYear - date2WeekOfYear) == 1 {
    // do some stuff
}
```

This works except in the case where date1 falls within the first week of the year, and date2 falls within the last week of the prior year.  Do I really have to also add in other logic to check the situation where the year components are different, and account for varying lengths of years in weeks (most have 52 weeks, some have 53), or is there a more elegant way to handle this?

Please note that I'm not interested in checking if the two dates are within 7 days of each other.  It's possible that the two days are within 2 days of each other, but fall within different weeks of the year.

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Perhaps add 7 days to one date (allowing for year roll-over), and determine difference in week number to be zero (not one)? I haven't tried your case, but I often do go about similar hairy problems in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way I found:

You *do* need to get the year, but `Calendar` can still do the calculation for you. You just need to call a different overload of the method from the one in Rob Napier's answer. You need the overload that accepts `DateComponents`:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let start = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1577375330) // 2019-12-26
let end = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1577893730) // 2020-01-01
// remember it's yearForWeekOfYear, not just "year"
let startDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: start)
let endDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: end)
let interval = calendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: startDateComponents, to: endDateComponents).weekOfYear!
print(interval) // 1
```

My speculation of why this works but the overload taking `Date`s doesn't:

The overload that takes `Date`s will first get the difference between the two dates, which represent *instants*, and then convert that time interval to the specified set of `DateComponent`s. Note that it's probably converting a `TimeInterval` to `DateComponent`s, which is why it can't calculate week boundaries and such.

The overload that takes `DateComponent`s *can* calculate week boundaries because that information is given as its parameters.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I needed.  Thank you to you and Rob Napier for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add 7 days to one date (allowing for year roll-over), and determine the difference in week-numbers between the two dates to be zero weeks rather then one week.

Have a look at the 2019 end of year

```
> var cal = Calendar.current
> let df = DateFormatter(); df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
> var d1 = df.date(from: "2019-12-28")!;
> var w1=cal.component(.weekOfYear, from:d1)
w1: Int = 52
```

This tells us Dec 28 still fell in week 52.

```
> var w2=cal.component(.weekOfYear, from: df.date(from: "2019-12-29")!)
w2: Int = 1
```

And this tells us Dec 29 fell in week 1 of 2020. These two dates are "1 week apart", as humans can easily tell. Determining this by calculation can be a bit harder, even if you use modulo arithmetic: the wrap-around is irregular, at 52 for some years, and 53 for others, as the OP hinted at. (2006, 2012, 2017 and 2023 are all 53-week years)

To determine that they are 1 week apart by calculation, first move up the earlier date by 7 days, i.e. 2019-12-28 plus 7 days:

```
> var d1_7 = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value:7, to:d1)!;
d1_7: Date = 2020-01-04 08:00:00 UTC
> var w1_7 = cal.component(.weekOfYear,from:d1_7)
w1_7: Int = 1
```

Its week number is 1, equalling that of 2019-12-29. We conclude that 2019-12-28 and 2019-12-29 are 1 week apart.